# MigLayout width - cell or Component?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I am not clear from the documentation - when I indicate a cell width

```
panel.add(cc,"width 100:200:300");
```

am I requesting a min:pref:max width for the cell or for the component in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience it is best to enforce this kind of constraints at the layout level, which achieves a more consistent behaviour.

For example,

```
new MigLayout("insets 0", "[:50:][grow,fill,:50:250]20[:50:][grow,fill,:50:]", "[c]")`
```

where the second parameter sets the layout properties for columns (four columns in this case with specific preferred and maximum widths). Then components are added to the container with this layout manager by simply calling

```
panel.add(cc);
```

with or without the "wrap" option (which indicates the need to create a new row).

Comment: Helpful - I will try that, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ed4becky My understanding is that the constraints in your example are for the component, and cells are governed by column constraints where they belong to.

Comment: So my example constrains the components and the one in this answer constraints the cells?

Comment: Correct. Technically speaking constraints in this answers govern columns and rows (third parameter). Cells are just intersections between columns and rows, and have to adhere to these constraints.